# How hard would I hit the ground on Mars?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, forces, newtonian-gravity

How do you calculate with how much force a mass would hit the ground when falling from a certain height?

In particular, I'm curious to know how the force of impact on Earth compares with Mars, so surface gravity needs to be accounted for.

According to [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravity_of_Earth#Comparative_gravities_of_the_Earth.2C_Sun.2C_Moon.2C_and_planets), Mars has a surface gravity of $3.711 m/s^2$ or $0.33895G$ and Earth has a surface gravity of $9.8067 m/s^2$ or $1G$. So, assuming a 100 meter fall, how hard would 100kg hit the ground?

Comment: That's why I'm asking @Floris. I don't understand the subtleties of the question. It's been a long time since I took a physics class.

Comment: @Floris If I remember my physics classes correctly then $v = \sqrt{2gh} $

Comment: @Vogel612 - of course you are right. $\frac12 m v^2 = m g h$ so $v = \sqrt{2 g h}$. Thanks for catching that. The formula in my answer is correct.

Comment: Downvoter, I'm new here. If there's something wrong with my question, please let me know so I can improve it.

Comment: By force do you mean impulse?

Comment: @Mehrdad I have no idea what you mean by "impulse", but I mean "how hard" in whatever is a meaningful measurement. I was originally thinking joules, but current answers are using Newtons. Which makes sense in hindsight.

Comment: @RubberDuck: Impulse is Newton-seconds, it basically means "apply a force F for T seconds". It should make sense that the force applied depends on the time over which it is applied, so the answer can't be in Newtons unless you specify the stopping time duration.

Comment: @Mehrdad or answerers have to think of a reasonable stopping duration... Sure it would be a better and easier homework, but that would be boring IMO

Comment: @Vogel612: The thing with stopping durations is that they can very a LOT. A stone floor has a much shorter stopping duration than a rug, and both are reasonable. Your glass will probably break when dropped on a hard floor but not a soft one.

Comment: *It's not the fall the kills you.*

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you absorb the fall from a height $h$ by bending your knees (so you decelerate over a distance $d$) then the force is simply the weight multiplied by the ratio $\frac{h}{d}$ (because the work done by gravity over distance $h$ must be absorbed over distance $d$). The general formula (for any mass m, gravity g, drop height h, absorption distance d) is

$$m\cdot g \cdot h = F \cdot d\\
F = \frac{h}{d} m g$$

So if you can absorb the shock over 1 m, you drop from 100 m, and gravity is $3.7 m/s^2$, then

$$F = \frac{100}{1}\cdot 3.7 \cdot 100 = 37 kN$$

The above explains why falling onto a trampoline or air bag doesn't hurt (much) - and why a hard floor does. It also explains why parachutists try to "fall" as they land - they again try to increase the distance over which they absorb the impact of landing.

If you are interested instead in decelerating in a certain *time*, then the formula you want is the impulse equation:

$$F\Delta t = m \Delta v$$

From conservation of energy, we get

$$v = \sqrt{2gh}$$

and thence you find

$$F = \frac{m\sqrt{2gh}}{\Delta t}$$

Note that this ignores the force of gravity during the deceleration.

As for the atmosphere: Mars atmosphere has a density of about $\mathrm{0.02 kg/m^3}$. This is <2% of earth's density at sea level so it is pretty safe to ignore it in these calculations.

Also note that the mean surface *acceleration* on Mars is $\mathrm{3.68 m/s^2}$ - the rotation slows you down about 1% so it matters where you fall (more than or earth because Mars is smaller).

[Nasa website with data on Mars](http://nssdc.gsfc.nasa.gov/planetary/factsheet/marsfact.html)

Comment: However air resistance is less on Mars than on Earth.

Comment: There is so little atmospheric resistance that the terminal velocity on Mars is more than five times the one on Earth. So if you fall from high enough (around 600m), you will hit the martian ground harder.

Answer (score 9):

The answer to this is relatively simple. Assuming an inexisting atmosphere (and thus terminal velocity) on mars, the kinetic energy of the weight equals its potential energy.

Potential energy is calculated relatively simple:

$$E_p = m \cdot g \cdot h$$

now if you wanted to find out how *fast* the mass would impact on mars, you can set this equal to the kinetic energy you get after completely using up that potential (aka. when you fall 100 m):

$$ \frac{1}{2} \cdot m \cdot v^2 = m \cdot g \cdot h$$

now with a little standard mathematics, you arrive at a formula for your velocity, depending on height of where you start from:

$$ v = \sqrt{2 \cdot g \cdot h} $$

Interestingly (and as mentioned in the already existing answer) the velocity can be removed from the equation. For the sake of the demonstration let's calculate it either way:

$$ v = \sqrt{2 \cdot 3.711 \frac{m}{s^2} \cdot 100 m} = \sqrt {742.2 \frac {m^2}{s^2}} = 27.24... \frac {m}{s}$$

This is a roundabout $100 \frac{km}{h}$, give or take. (or a little more than 60 mph).

Anyways since you wanted to know about the "Force" of the collision...

How much force  does it take to stop $100kg$ with a velocity of $100 \frac{km}{h}$?

The question here is... How *fast* do you want to stop? The slower you stop, the less continuously applied force is required.

When we multiply our velocity and the mass we get an Impulse (which is $F \cdot\Delta t$ or $m \cdot v $). We now know the impulse of our mass: $2700 Ns$

To get this stopped in a tenth of a second (which is an extremely optimistic guess, assuming falling on the hard mars), you need a whopping: $27 kN$